# MySQL 5.7 doesn't start after installation on CentOS 6.7

Tags: mysql, installation, centos

I have just installed MySQL 5.7 on a fresh CentOS 6.7(vm).

When I start the MySQL service with this command:

```
sudo service mysqld start
```

It doesn't start and raise this error:

> Initializing MySQL database: 2015-12-07T11:00:51.060114Z 0 [Warning]
>   TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use
>   --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details). 2015-12-07T11:00:51.062305Z 0 [ERROR]
>   --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. 
>   Aborting. 2015-12-07T11:00:51.062347Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting [FAILED]

---

Do you know what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue myself and I successfully resolved it.
What needs to be done is:
Open the `my.conf` file in vi editor and add a line under `[mysqld]`:

```
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 1
```

This will fix the first issue.
Now check the access rights of the location pointed by `datadir` field and make sure mysql can access it. 
Worst case rename the location it points to. eg:

```
datadir=/var/lib/mysql1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below steps

```
mysqld --initialize-insecure --user=username --datadir=datadir_path
```

you can also opt to `--initialize-secure`, but it would ask for root password as it was in previous versions with `secure_installation`.

Make sure the `datadir` is an empty created folder or else it will throw errors and then you can use following to start `mysql`:

```
./bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=path to cnf file
```

or

```
serivce mysqld start
```

Please check for error log file and share if you face any errors following above steps and do set root password once it is started.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, (I suppose it's bug of MySql) right now I have solved the same issue. In my case I have created separated partition (mount point) for MySQL database. There was created the directory "lost+found". You should temporary move it or other files or folders to any other place and clean /var/lib/mysql . After this just run again "sudo service mysqld start" then you will see something like this:

Initializing MySQL database:                               [  OK  ]
Installing validate password plugin:                       [  OK  ]
Starting mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Kubernetes and MySQL 5.7 as well.

Adding the suggestion from [yosifki](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/186#issuecomment-229480846) to my container's definition got things working.

> A new ext4 disk partition is not usually empty;
> there is a lost+found directory, which mysql is known to choke on. You
> could try adding --ignore-db-dir=lost+found to the CMD to know for
> sure (from [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_ignore-db-dir))

Here's an extract of my working YAML definition:

```
name: mysql-master
image: mysql:5.7
args:
  - "--ignore-db-dir=lost+found"
```

Here's an example snippet in docker-compose to clarify:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql-master:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: [--ignore-db-dir=lost+found]
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
```